# WFE's out of Synch

Tags: central-administration

I have 2 SharePoint WFE Servers, due to some changes by my previous administrator, one of the WFE is out of synch. Can you please suggest.. what could be the issue?

Example: When a create a new web application, it creates the website only on One WFE and not on other. ANother thing.. when I am creating a new web application.. "Opeartion in Progress " continues for ever...

Please suggest.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you running?

Answer (score 2):

restarting the timer services should resolve the issue if the server is healthy.

You can also run stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs to initiate any pending changes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

We faced a similar problem in MOSS 2007 environment . where the webapplication is  created in one server and it is not created in the other.

The steps which we did was delete the webapplication first

Restart the timer services in both the WFE and try creating a webapplication . This should solve

Comment: It worked. Thanks !! Restarted the timer services in both the WFE and again created the web application.